# Calling function from request function in views Django

Tags: python, django

I have simple html template with link, that starts script, in views that retrieves data to the page,in views file I have two functions: render function `def output(request):`(it retrieves data to the page) and another function `def summoner():` that makes postgres quires in cycle and appends results to the list. Separately each of them work fine, but I have to call second function from render function and retrieve the data to the page, but now when I do that all I am getting is empty list.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWuLS.png)

template:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Python  script
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="{% url 'script' %}">Execute Script</a> <hr>
        {% if data %}


        {{ data }}


        {% endif %}

        </body>
</html>
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import os, glob


conn = psycopg2.connect(host='127.0.0.1', database='db',
                        user='user', password='pass')
cur = conn.cursor()


def insert_data_as_is(file_name):
    cur.execute('truncate table test_inv.start_tbl')
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        cur.execute("insert into test_inv.start_tbl values {0}".format(file.read()))
        conn.commit()


def insert_data_to_be(file_name):
    cur.execute('truncate table test_inv.res_calc_ratios_t')
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        cur.execute('insert into test_inv.res_calc_ratios_t (test_no, test_name, hcode_id, '
                    'hcode_name, hcode_'
                    'unit_name,'
                    ' org_id, dor_kod, duch_id, nod_id, date_type_id, metric_type_id, cargo_type_id, val_type_id,'
                    ' unit_id, dt, value, ss, dir_id, kato_id, vids_id) values {0}'.format(file.read()))
        conn.commit()



path_start = 'files/csv_s/as_is/'
start_list = []
path_finish = 'files/csv_s/to_be'
finish_list = []
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_start, '*.*')):
    start_list.append(infile)
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_finish, '*.*')):
    finish_list.append(infile)


 def summoner():
    fun_sql_set = []
    fun_query = """select * from test_inv.test_ratios('1','15')"""
    for i in range(len(finish_list)):
        insert_data_as_is(start_list[i])
        insert_data_to_be(finish_list[i])
        results = pd.read_sql_query(fun_query, conn)
        fun_sql_set.append(results)
    return fun_sql_set



def index(request):
    return render(request,'calculus/index.html')



def output(request):
    data = summoner()
    print(data)
    return render(request,'calculus/index.html',{'data':data})
```

Comment: What are you getting in `print(data)` output?

Comment: Yes, I know that but you are getting something in data or not?

Comment: can you please add debug in `summoner ()` at before return statement  as `print(fun_sql_set)`. And check, that `summoner()` successfully generated required data or not.

Comment: an empty list, here screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWuLS.png

Comment: It means you wrote wrong logic in `summoner()`.

Comment: As i said before i can call summoner from another function and it retrieve result, so i think summoner logic works fine. https://imgur.com/F1RKiIA

Comment: I think i create a wrong files path, now its looks like this, its works then i call that function from the file but Django can access it:
`p_s = './static/csv_s/as_is/'
path_start = os.path.dirname(p_s)
start_list = []
p_f = './static/csv_s/to_be/'
path_finish = os.path.dirname(p_f)
finish_list = []
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_start, '*.*')):
    start_list.append(infile)
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_finish, '*.*')):
    finish_list.append(infile)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is creating absolute file path:

```
cur_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path_start = '{}/static/csv_s/as_is/'.format(cur_dir)
path_finish = '{}/static/csv_s/to_be/'.format(cur_dir)
```